# C# Visual Studio - Outputting SQL table data to Datagridview

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, datagridview

Apologies if this has been covered. The examples I seemed to find were more complicated than I need it to be

I'm trying to output the entire contents of an SQL table to a DatagridView when a button "Display All Records" is clicked

I'm having a bit of trouble, here is what I have so far

```
  private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                string query = "select * from student";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();


                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

                da.Fill(DataGridView);
                con.Close();
                da.Dispose();
            }
```

Here is all my code if you need to refer

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True");



        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            establishConnection();


        }

        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {


            Boolean postSuccess = false;

            if (validation() == true)
            {

                SqlCommand details = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Student (Firstname, LastName, MatriculationNo, GradeOne, GradeTwo, GradeThree) VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @MatriculationNo, @GradeOne, @GradeTwo, @GradeThree)", con);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", firstnameTextbox.Text);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", lastnameTextbox.Text);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MatriculationNo", matriculationnoTextbox.Text);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeOne", Component1Textbox.Text);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeTwo", Component2Textbox.Text);
                details.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GradeThree", Component3Textbox.Text);
                con.Open();
                details.ExecuteNonQuery();
                postSuccess = true;

                if (postSuccess)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Details entered succesfully!");
                    firstnameTextbox.Clear();
                    lastnameTextbox.Clear();
                    matriculationnoTextbox.Clear();
                    Component1Textbox.Clear();
                    Component2Textbox.Clear();
                    Component3Textbox.Clear();

                }

                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data not entered succesfully, please check DB connection");
                }
                con.Close();
            }

        }
        private void establishConnection()
        {
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("Connected to SQL database");

                connectionLabel.Content = "Connected to SQL Database";

                con.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {

                connectionLabel.Content = "not connected to sql database";
            }
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            firstnameTextbox.Clear();  //Clears the first name textbox
            lastnameTextbox.Clear();   //Clears the last name textbox
            matriculationnoTextbox.Clear(); //Clears the Matriculation Number textbox
            Component1Textbox.Clear(); //Clears the component one textbox
            Component2Textbox.Clear(); //Clears the component two textbox
            Component3Textbox.Clear(); //Clears the component three textbox
        }


        private Boolean validation()
        {
            if (!Regex.Match(firstnameTextbox.Text, "^[A-Z][a-zA-Z]*$").Success)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please Enter a valid First Name");
                firstnameTextbox.Clear();
                return false;
            }
            else
            {
                return true;
            }

        }

        private void Button_Click_3(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            con.Open(); 
            string sql = @"DELETE FROM Student;"; //Deleting all from Student table
            SqlCommand purge = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
            MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to purge the entire contents of the database?"); //Prompting user to make sure they want to delete
            purge.ExecuteNonQuery(); //Execute purge query


        }

        private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            {

                string query = "select * from student";
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                con.Open();

                // create data adapter
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
                da.Fill(DataGridView);
                con.Close();
                da.Dispose();
            }









        }





    }
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just fill `DataTable` with your table and bind it to `GridView.DataContext`.

Like so:

First Add `DataGrid` in XAML editor `<DataGrid Name="customDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">`

then Code behind:

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
        /// <summary>
        /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
        /// </summary>
        public partial class MainWindow : Window
        {
            string connectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

            public MainWindow()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                DataTable table = null;
                string query = "select * from student";
                try
                {
                    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(this.connectionString))
                    {
                        connection.Open();
                        using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, connection))
                        {
                            table = new DataTable();
                            adapter.Fill(table);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //handle caught exception
                }

                if (table != null)
                {
                    customDataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;
                }
            }
        }
}
```

> Binding part: `customDataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;`

Comment: Hi SeM, Thanks for quick reply. It is giving me an errorError 1 The type or namespace name 'DataTable' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) h:\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication4\WpfApplication4\MainWindow.xaml.cs 138 13 WpfApplication4

Comment: also,      Error 3 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' does not contain a definition for 'DataSource' and no extension method 'DataSource' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) h:\visual studio 2013\Projects\WpfApplication4\WpfApplication4\MainWindow.xaml.cs 159 31 WpfApplication4

Comment: First error: Add the reference `using System.Data;`

Comment: Second: You cast your dataGridView1 as `DataGrid`, but you need to cast as `DataGridView`

Comment: Hi first one worked perfect, When I try to get the DataGridView from the toolbox it is just blanked out with a blocked symbol? wont let me drag and drop. Thanks again for all your help

Comment: Ok, I've got it, it because your project is WPF project, `DataGridView` is Windows Forms Control, you need to add `DataGrid` like this: `<DataGrid Name="customDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}">`, then bind filled table like this: `customDataGrid.DataContext = table.DefaultView;`

Answer (score 0):

try this....

```
    private void Button_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string query = "select * from student";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
        con.Open();

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        // create data adapter
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        // this will query your database and return the result to your datatable
        da.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();
        da.Dispose();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        MySqlCommand command = conn.CreateCommand();
        command.CommandText = "Select * from student";
        try
        {
            con.Open();

            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = command;
            DataTable dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();

            bSource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
```

Try this